# Codificación librería PHPExcelReader

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Tengo el siguiente problema con la codificación de la librería PHPEXCELREADER: Cuando leo un archivo excel y obtengo una celda que contiene tilde me muestra un signo de interrogación en vez de el caracter apropiado. Por ejemplo si en la celda esta la palabra "josé" me mostrará "jos?".

He buscado por internet como solucionar este problema y aun no he dado con la solución.

El código es el siguiente:

```
    require_once 'Excel/reader.php';
    $tags = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
    $tags->setOutputEncoding('utf-16');
    $tags->read('uploads/Tags/'.$datos->excel->nombre_archivo_tags);
    echo utf8_decode($tags->sheets[0]['cells'][$index][$nom_r + 0]);
```

Espero alguien sepa como solucionar este problema, saludos!!

Comment: Revisa este problema en SO en ingles, quizas te puede ayudar: [php-excel-reader-problem-with-utf-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666412/php-excel-reader-problem-with-utf-8)

Comment: ¿Has probado a coordinar las líneas `$tags->setOutputEncoding('utf-16');` y `echo utf8_decode($tags->sheets[0]['cells'][$index][$nom_r + 0]);`? Parece que das codificaciones distintas de salida. Por otra parte en el enlace de @StefanNolde puedes ver la que tuve que usar yo en otra ocasión con un problema parecido, la de Windows `cp1250`. Te recomiendo que imprimar el código numérico de esos caracteres que te dan problemas para ver a cuál corresponde en distintas tablas de caracteres.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas!! He logrado solucionarlo con sus sugerencias,  muchas gracias